# How to create database from the C# code in MVC 4 project

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, multiple-databases

I am working on MVC 4 web app using Entitiy framework 5. I have an users membership database and an administration which divides data of the website into factories and for each factory i need a different database.
Here is where my problem comes :

I need to create a new database into the master with predefined tables and stored procedures with sql script from the C# code. But for this i cannot use entity framework as i saw. I have found some ways with ado sql command calls, but it requires to mix up EF with raw ado.net .

My question is:

Is there a way to execute sql script for creating a whole database from the C# code using EF5 somehow ?

For now the only way that i have found is this :
[Code to create & connect to a SQL Server database: Whats wrong with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321206/code-to-create-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-whats-wrong-with-it)

Any suggestions would be heplful. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833650/create-new-database-programmatically-in-asp-net-mvc-application  maybe helps you

Answer (score 1):

Look at EntityFramework with code first deployments.

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create the database and then use this tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx. This should help